# Error reading JSON file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to read a json file in AngularJS using $http.get and get some errors in browser console.

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/SDRpu1MmrTPpgpdb6Kyk?p=preview

Here is my code

**Javascript:-**

```
var jayApp = angular.module('jayApp', []);

jayApp.controller('jayController', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.entities = {};

    $http.get("test.json").success(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.entities = data;
        }
    );
})
```

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='jayApp' ng-controller='jayController'>
    <h1>Read Json from file </h1>

    Data : {{entities}}
  </body>

</html>
```

**Update:**

**Error**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:1252:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:9414:16)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:9505:12
    at forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:336:20)
    at transformData (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:9504:3)
    at transformResponse (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:10276:23)
    at processQueue (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:14745:28)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:14761:27
    at Scope.$eval (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:15989:28)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12477(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9246processQueue @ angular.js:14753(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14761Scope.$eval @ angular.js:15989Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15800Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16097done @ angular.js:10546completeRequest @ angular.js:10744requestLoaded @ angular.js:10685
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @jcubic Thanks I have updated with errors.

Comment: You can use http://jsoneditoronline.org/ to verify your JOSN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your plunker had two issues. first the path to the JSON file was wrong resulting in a `404`. Remove the leading `/` fixed that issue.

The root problem is your `JSON` is invalid.

It should be

```
{
  "name":"jay",
  "city":"Tanjore"
}
```

you had single quotes (') but need to use double (").

Comment: Many thanks can you please check this link  http://plnkr.co/edit/SDRpu1MmrTPpgpdb6Kyk?p=info   its a different json ?  Is this a problem with this JSON ? This JSON was generated from our app.

Comment: @Jay Looking at the console no it is not. If you press `f12` in most browsers it will answer most of these question for you. It is throwing exceptions trying to parse it. Also running it through a [json validator](http://jsonlint.com/) it fails. Looking at it have you pulled it from a console? It looks like its already been parsed. JSON is a raw string, it describes a JS object. Properies and SOME values need to be enclosed in double quotes (")

Comment: @Jay i think yore having issues understanding JSON. May i suggest you have a read on it. First in your `http` success you do not need to manually parse the response. Angular will do that in this example. Second all your property names need to be enclosed in double quotes, so do any string values. Lastly you were missing a pair of curly braces({}) around the enitre JSON. You had this `entityPropertyTypes:[]` which is defining an object property however you were missing the braces to define an object litteral so it should be `{ entityPropertyTypes: [] }`

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue with your JSON and you need to put the Path of the file without '/'

**JSON:**

```
{
  "name":"jay",
  "city":"Tanjore"
}
```

**CODE:**

```
$http.get("test.json").success(
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
        $scope.entities = data;
    }
);
```

Here is the updated [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/bPS4BC1MkphnYJpVfbXB?p=preview)

Comment: Many thanks can you please check this link http://plnkr.co/edit/SDRpu1MmrTPpgpdb6Kyk  its a different json ?

Answer (score 1):

Invalid JSON... Should be:

```
{
  "name":"jay",
  "city":"Tanjore"
}
```

Also, on your Plunk you are making the call to the wrong place (get rid of the / before test.json).

$http.get("test.json").success( ...

Answer (score 1):

1. as i see into your json file ,you have some syntax errors that is your first main error, so the interpreter cannot read the json data.
   A.  i just added  double quotes to your `**keys**` and 
   B.  i enclosed all your json object into curly brakets `**{}**`
2. **you cant parse a file that is already json object, you parse a json file when you stringify it**. So, i remove the 'parse word' and i leave it like this:

   ```
       $http.get("test.json").success(
           function(data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.entities =data;  
           }
        );
   ```

fixed plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/G5Y62tQuJit3ZvjHbKQ8?p=preview

i didnt add double quotes to all your *keys* because they too many , but it is enough to understand your mistake.
[image]
hope helps good luck.